# Mapbox GeoJSON loaded via local URL: icons not showing popup properties

Tags: javascript, css, geojson, mapbox

In my web site, I am using a Mapbox map to load icons from a URL procured like so:

```
/* myMapbox.js */
map = L.mapbox.map("map", "somemap.hhlj93e3").setView([47.60,-122.33], 13);
...
.someAjaxCall{

   allMyIcons = L.mapbox.featureLayer ().loadURL ("/updatedIcons");
   allMyIcons.addTo (map);
}
```

The icons loaded via `/updatedIcons` do show up, but they were not clickable. I solved the clickability problem using this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056840/mapbox-markers-not-showing-clickable-cursor-on-mouseover/23280758#23280758). However, the properties for each feature (icon) retrieved via the `/updatedIcons` call still do not show up as a popup when I click the icons (nothing happens when I click the icons). Note that the icons created at the Mapbox site for `somemap` user do show up on the map, and they are clickable, and a popup happily shows up for them *on the same map*.

Here's a sample of my GeoJSON loaded via `/updatedIcons`:

```
[{
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [-77.03, 38.90]},
"properties": {
    "image":   "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Cherry_Blossoms_and_Washington_Monument.jpg/320px-Cherry_Blossoms_and_Washington_Monument.jpg",
    "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington,_D.C.",
    "marker-symbol": "star",
    "city": "Washington, D.C."
}
}, {
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [-87.63, 41.88]},
"properties": {
    "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Chicago_sunrise_1.jpg/640px-Chicago_sunrise_1.jpg",
    "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago",
    "city": "Chicago"
}
}, {
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [-74.00, 40.71]},
"properties": {
    "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/39/NYC_Top_of_the_Rock_Pano.jpg/640px-NYC_Top_of_the_Rock_Pano.jpg",
    "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_City",
    "city": "New York City"
}
}]
```

What am I missing here? Just to be clear, the icons appear, but they weren't clickable until I added the CSS improvements mentioned in the linked SO post, and now, I can click the icons, but nothing happens (the properties don't show up in a popup). I understand the GeoJSON example above is a FeatureCollection, and I included the above in a

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": <content from above GeoJSON here>
}
```

but that hasn't changed the behavior. Is this a layering issue? If so, how to merge all the layers in my map? I will have the base map loaded from Mapbox, a marker created by user which I want to render using

```
       marker = L.marker ([lat, lng],
              {
                  icon: L.divIcon ({
                  iconSize: [10, 10]
                  })
              });
```

and the icons loaded from `/updatedIcons` above, all of which I want to be clickable.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`L.mapbox.featureLayer`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v1.6.2/l-mapbox-featurelayer/) inherits from [`L.mapbox.featureGroup`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v1.6.2/l-featuregroup/).

And to add (or bind) a popup to a `featureGroup` you'll want something like this

```
allMyIcons = L.mapbox.featureLayer().loadURL("/updatedIcons");
allMyIcons.bindPopup("Howdy!");
allMyIcons.addTo(map);
```

If you would rather each marker/icon to have its own unique popup, you can loop through them like this, adding the unique popup as you iterate

```
allMyIcons.eachLayer(function (layer) {
layer.bindPopup('Howdy: ' + count);
    count += 1;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your clarifying response. While I think the response from Mapbox support answered my question directly (I.e., why don't my properties show up?), the Mapbox support person didn't respond here. I will accept his answer if he responds here, but for people looking for an answer to my question here, the answer is below. If he doesn't respond on SO by the end of this week, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the response from Mapbox support:

The popups you see on maps are formatted based on specific properties - by default, these properties are 'title' and 'description'. Features without these default properties don't automatically get default popups, because the code wouldn't know what means what - whether something should be shown as a title or a description, or an image is unclear. Since your data doesn't contain the default properties, you'll have to specify how tooltips are formatted, like so, with bindPopup: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/omnivore-kml-tooltip/ http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-bindpopup